# Limiting number of items that can be move from one Listbox to another

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to move no more than 8 selected items from Listbox1 to Listbox2.  Both Listboxes are multi-select. When I select more than 8 items and move them at once to Listbox2, these items are not removed from Listbox1.  However, the items are removed from Listbox1 when I move them individually, with exception of the item number 8.

The code works well if I don’t try to limit the number of items that can be moved but I'm having difficulty getting it to work with the specified condition (only 8 items in Listbox2).

I looked around on-line but couldn't find a good example. I would really appreciate advice. I also would like to know if what I'm trying to do is not possibile.

```
    Private Sub BTN_MoveSelectedRight_Click()

    Dim iCtr As Long

        For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1


            If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True And Not ListBox2.ListCount = 8 Then
                Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCtr)

            End If

        Next iCtr

        For iCtr = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True And Not ListBox2.ListCount = 8 Then
                Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem iCtr

            End If
        Next iCtr


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will move first 8 selected items from listbox1 to listbox2 and if listbox2 have 8 items will do nothing, I don't know if that is what you need.

```
Private Sub BTN_MoveSelectedRight_Click()
   Dim iCtr As Long
   Dim i As Long
   Dim j As Long
   Dim arr(8) As Long

        For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1

            If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True And Not ListBox2.ListCount = 8 Then
                Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCtr)

                arr(i) = iCtr
                i = i + 1
            End If

          If i = 8 Then Exit For
        Next iCtr

        For j = i - 1 To 0 Step -1
         Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem arr(j)
        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListBox.ListCount` returns the number of items in your `Listox`. If you want to obtain the number of selected items, then you'd need this kind of function:

```
Private Function SelectedCount(lbox As msforms.ListBox) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sel As Integer

    For i = 0 To lbox.ListCount - 1
        If lbox.Selected(i) Then sel = sel + 1
    Next

    SelectedCount = sel
End Function
```

If you wanted to, you could keep track of selections and whenever the user selected a ninth item, unselect the oldest item. This way your `ListBox` would always have the eight (or fewer) most recently selected items. You could do that like so:

```
Option Explicit
Private mEnableUserEvents As Boolean
Private mSelectionOrder As Collection
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Dim key As String

    If Not mEnableUserEvents Then Exit Sub
    key = CStr(ListBox1.ListIndex)
    If ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListIndex) Then
        mSelectionOrder.Add ListBox1.ListIndex, CStr(ListBox1.ListIndex)
        If mSelectionOrder.Count = 9 Then
            mEnableUserEvents = False
            ListBox1.Selected(mSelectionOrder.Item(1)) = False
            mEnableUserEvents = True
            mSelectionOrder.Remove 1
        End If
    Else
        mSelectionOrder.Remove key
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    mEnableUserEvents = True
    Set mSelectionOrder = New Collection
End Sub
```